# Is there any source code for Vuforia's Text recognition [For android]

Tags: vuforia

I'm working on Vuforia with android on Eclipse. I need the source code of the sample app **Text Recognition**

The apk file is given in the Samples Tab of www.developer.vuforia.com

But I need the source code for the same. [If available]

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you should go to this [link](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sample-apps) to download the source code file.
then put it in samples directory of your **vuforia sdk**

Comment: Thanks. But I could find only apk file given for this particular project. And moreover it is not identifying digits.

Comment: just click on **android** link under the **download sample** title, it's not apk file,it's the source of all samples. And yes, it doesn't recognize digits.for this problem maybe you should see this [link](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/word-targets)@Frankenstein